# Recv() on a socket() not Receiving somehow (embedded Linux c/c++)

Tags: c, linux, string, sockets

Currently I have a client/server implementation of C code. I have done a lot to follow different books and implementations, and ultimately it doesn't work.

Referencing the "printf" statements below, I can say that the client succeeds in sending the message, but the server never passes the receive stage (even after the client has supposedly succeeded in sending).

So ultimately I get the impression that there is something either with the way my server is receiving the code OR something to do with the formatting what I am sending (when I say this I mean that I am possibly missing \0 or \r\n or something though I believe I am including them quite anally).

Here is the relevant code with much removed:

SERVER:

```
int Server::update(char *getbuf)
{

...

// ACCEPT
        clientsocket = accept(serversocket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &alen);
if(!clientsocket)
            logger.fail("Accept Fail");
else
logger.info("Accept succeed");


    z = recv (clientsocket, sbuf, sSize, MSG_DONTWAIT);


    snprintf(&sbuf[z], sSize-z, "\r\n\0");


    snprintf(getbuf, sSize, sbuf);


    logger.data("Received: %s",sbuf);       

        respond(getbuf);

        return TRUE;
    }

returnFALSE;
}


void Server::respond(char *response)
{
// SEND
ssize_t z;
    int sSize = 64;
    char sbuf[sSize];


    snprintf(sbuf, sSize, response);
    snprintf(&sbuf[z], sSize-z, "\r\n\0");


    z = send(clientsocket, sbuf, sSize, 0);
    if (z < 0)
fprintf(stderr,"send failure\n");
    else
logger.info("Send Succeed");
}
```

CLIENT

```
Code:

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
...

    z = connect(com_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    if(z == -1)
    {
        if(errno == EINPROGRESS)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EINPROGRESS non block start\n");
        }

        if(errno == EALREADY)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EALREADY non block subsequent request\n");
        }

        fprintf(stderr, "Connect failed\n");
    }
    else 
    printf("Connect Success\n");


    int sSize = 64;
    char sbuf[sSize];


    z = snprintf(sbuf, sSize, command);
        snprintf(&sbuf[z], sSize-z, "\r\n\0");


// SEND
    z = send(com_socket, sbuf, sSize, 0);
    if (z < 0)
        fprintf(stderr,"send failure\n");
    else
    printf("Send Succeeded\n");

// READ
    z = recv(com_socket, sbuf, sSize, MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if (z < 0)
        fprintf(stderr,"receive failure\n");
    else
    printf("Receive Succeeded\n");

    snprintf(&sbuf[z], sSize-z,"\r\n\0");


// Output
    printf("Received Response: %s\n", sbuf);

    close(com_socket);

    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Vague question, giant pile of code.  No.

Comment: If you can pare down your code to the relevant part, define exactly what the problem is, and the problem doesn't become obvious, we can perhaps reopen the question and explain. Debuggers are good, though.

Comment: Tl;dr. In the future please outline your question concisely.

Comment: Please reopen this question. I do have a valid answer that points out several bugs that may be responsible for the OP's lack of success.

Comment: Nathan - in your server code, you are passing MSG_DONTWAIT to the recv call, but you are not checking the return value (z).  Which means if the sent data is not immediately available, then "-1" will get returned and assigned to z. And that will do bad things with the pointer math you do in subsequent snprintf calls.  That's the first bug I see.  I suspect I can find several more.....

Comment: In Server::respond function - "z" variable never gets initialized. That's likely your core problem.  You would be better off to just do two sends "send(clientsock, response, strlen(response, 0); send(clientsock, "\r\n\0", 3, 0);".  That's a lot more safer than doing pointer math.

Comment: Client code. Don't bother with MSG_DONTWAIT in recv. That's going to cause recv to fail randomly based on timing issues.  Another client bug - even though the server may have sent you N bytes, you only attempt to consume it in one call to recv.  If the TCP stream gets fragmented, recv will return any value between 1 and (N-1). You need to continually call recv until you get all the data you expect the server to send. In your case, keep calling recv and appedn the result until you get a \0 in the recveive stream.

Comment: @selbie: The fact that you have an answer doesn't justify the existence of the question. StackOverflow has various rules about what kinds of questions are permitted, and this is a kind that's definitely not.

Comment: @Jefromi - agree and disagree. Agree that his question didn't show much attempt to solve the issue by himself. (e.g. He's basically saying, "Hey, please debug my program for me!").  Disagree that he didn't do enough to state the problem or post enough to generate a valid answer. In any case, I have an idea that I'll bring up on meta.

Comment: @selbie: This has never been a site for debugging. If there are unknown problems in hundreds of line of code, then the question is overly broad, as described in the close reasons. This particular one was also ambiguous, because it didn't even clearly describe the problem that was occurring. It was absolutely an appropriate question to close, even if someone as motivated and helpful as you was able to scan through it and debug.

Comment: @Jefromi - IMHO, his question was very clear.  He just didn't ask it in a very reasonable manner. I interpreted it as,  "Here's my socket code. The server code is working fine, but the client doesn't seem to get or print a resaponse."  I suspect if he actually phrased it that way, had a better title (e.g. "recv not returning expected data"), trimmed his code down to a more minimal example, and showed some evidence he debugged it, it probably wouldn't get voted down. I've seen a whole lost worse allowed - I'm not convinced the close rules are applied equally throughout SO. My 2cents.

Comment: Nathan - I do partially agree with Jefromi that your question was not the most appropriate style of posting. (Although, I'm happy to answer away at almost anything...). In the future, you should show some evidence that you actually tried to debug the issue yourself. As it stands now, it looks like you copied and pasted a bunch of socket code that you didn't understand yourself and are subsequently asking for help debugging. (Your question title implies frustration instead of a real question.) See my comment above on how your question could have been better formed.

Comment: I don't know what I can do to have this reopened, but I pasted the relevant server/client code because it was relevant to my client server issue. I have been slagged for not giving enough example code in the past, so really this is a teetering issue. I tried to state it clearly but I imagine not enough and will try again (with the assumption) that it can be re-opened? @Selbie thank you for the help. PS the title was a joke.

Comment: @NathanMcDavitt-VanFleet - The humorous title to your post is what attracted the attention of the TSA agents who like to robo-close questions without blinking. I don't always agree with their decisions, but I do understand the criteria they use. In any case, it doesn't appear you tried very hard to debug the issue - either with a debugger, network sniffer, or just simple print statements in code. In other words, more direct evidence of where you think the problem is occuring. I pointed out at least 4 seperate bugs. Start with that and repost with details if that doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure how to debug effectively, I am cross-compiling and have V=99 without much coming out in regards to warnings. I will try the MSG_DONTWAIT stuff and will update if I hit another snag. Thanks again

Comment: @selbie it appears it was at to do with the MSG_ flag. Thank you.

Comment: it looks like you are applying non-blocking model in a blocking situation.convert "MSG_DONTWAIT" to 0 or anything that blocks